# Firebase Cloud Storage Bandwidth too high after deploying few cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Today I upgraded from spark plan to blaze plan to deploy firebase function for my project, after writing firebase cloud function I saw my cloud storage bandwidth used to 51.8% of its daily quota.

I couldn't understand this usage, Could someone elaborate how is this calculated and is there any way to optimize this usage.